Handling Microsoft SafeLinks Double Activation in Email Links with AMPscript
I'm currently facing a challenge with Microsoft SafeLinks in an email marketing context. SafeLinks, a feature in Microsoft's security suite, pre-fetches URLs for security checks and then again when a user actually clicks through. This double activation is causing issues in my Salesforce Marketing Cloud environment, where we use AMPscript for dynamic content rendering and data logging.
The problem arises because SafeLinks pre-fetches the link, potentially triggering data recording or other actions unintentionally when the URL is first accessed. Then, the actual user click also triggers these actions again, leading to duplicate entries or incorrect data handling.
I'm looking for insights or strategies to detecting whether a URL access is from SafeLinks' pre-fetching or an actual user click.
In AMPscript, is there a way to retrieve the status code of a request, or check for specific QueryParameter that Outlook might add when SafeLinks processes the link?
Has anyone else encountered this problem, and how have you managed to differentiate between SafeLinks activations and genuine user interactions? Any specific AMPscript or general strategy recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

I remember a solution by eliot harper that checks "how fast the links were clicked" , basically assuming that a click that's within milliseconds of send time is a bot.
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/eliot_salesforcemarketingcloud-activity-6950907482886025216-Ml78
The solution is basically to check inside of the email using GetSendTime() AMPScript and ensuring that for a couple of milliseconds, unsub links get replaced.
This goes to show, it's almost impossible to "fix" this.
His solution is around unsubscription specifically, where he addresses it with an equally valid solution (two-step unsubscription) and does it for ONE link. You'd have to do it for ALL links, which sounds impractical.
Post-hoc (meaning from the logfiles alone), this might be quite the pain to work through, but you'd have to guesstimate a time after which you consider clicks "valid".
